# Why reducing an initialized Array of X length doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

While trying to build an indexed object of X length, I realised the following code wasn't working, but I can't get why it doesn't:

```
Array(X).reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    console.log(acc, curr, index);
    return acc;
}, {});
// => Object {}
```

The inner `console.log` should print values for every iteration (X times), but it looks like it's never called and the resulting value is just the `initialValue` we passed as parameter to the `reduce` method.

Does anyone could explain me why the reducer is not called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not called because your array is actually empty.

> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer
>   between 0 and 232-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array
>   with its length property set to that number (Note: this implies an
>   array of arrayLength empty slots, **not slots with actual undefined
>   values**)

You can do :

```
Array(X).fill().reduce(...)
```

See [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) doc

Comment: So **not slots with actual undefined values** is the important part here. Indeed, `Array(X).fill().reduce(...)` fills the array with `undefined` values then calls the reducer X times. Thanks!